# AutoIt _Timer_SetTimer - Additional callback arguments

Tags: callback, arguments, autoit

Using AutoIt 3, is there a way to pass additional arguments to the callback method in the [`_Timer_SetTimer`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_Timer_SetTimer.htm) function?

Here's my use case (main loop) :

```
For $item In $items
    _Timer_SetTimer(0, $timeOffset, "MyMethod")
Next
```

Callback method :

```
Func MyMethod($hWnd, $iMsg, $iTimerID, $iTime)
    _Timer_KillTimer ( $hWnd, $iTimerID )

    // Do something on $item

EndFunc
```

I tried using a `Global` variable, but every single instance of `MyMethod` then uses the last value. I did it this way :

```
Global $currentItem

For $item In $items
    $currentItem = $item
    _Timer_SetTimer(0, $timeOffset, "MyMethod")
Next

Func MyMethod($hWnd, $iMsg, $iTimerID, $iTime)
    _Timer_KillTimer ( $hWnd, $iTimerID )

    $item = $currentItem
    // Do something on $item

EndFunc
```

So, am I doing it wrong or is there a way to pass argument directly? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your delayed calls are ordered, you could still use a Global variable to store the values in an Array :

```
Global $values[0]

For $item In $items
     _ArrayAdd($values, $item)
     _Timer_SetTimer(0, $timeOffset, "MyMethod")
Next

Func MyMethod($hWnd, $iMsg, $iTimerID, $iTime)
     _Timer_KillTimer ( $hWnd, $iTimerID )

     _ArrayReverse($values)
     $item = _ArrayPop($values)
     _ArrayReverse($values)

    // Do something on $item

EndFunc
```

The double reverse and pop are there to simulate a FIFO queue